# A problem from Pathria, canonical ensemble, how to calculate $\left\langle \left(\Delta E\right)^{3}\right\rangle $

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

This is problem 3.18, from the book Statistical Mechanics by Pathria. Show that for a system in the canonical ensemble
$$\left\langle \left(\Delta E\right)^{3}\right\rangle =k^{2}\left\{ T^{4}\left(\frac{\partial C_{V}}{\partial T}\right)_{V}+2T^{3}C_{V}\right\} $$
Verify that for an ideal gas
$$\left\langle \left(\frac{\Delta E}{U}\right)^{2}\right\rangle =\frac{2}{3N},\qquad\left\langle \left(\frac{\Delta E}{U}\right)^{3}\right\rangle =\frac{8}{9N^{2}}$$
I have no Idea how to solve it.
I found that
$$\left\langle \left(\Delta E\right)^{3}\right\rangle \equiv\left\langle \left(E-\left\langle E\right\rangle \right)^{3}\right\rangle =\left\langle E^{3}\right\rangle -3\left\langle E\right\rangle \left\langle (\Delta E)^{2}\right\rangle -\left\langle E\right\rangle ^{3}$$
And using the fact that 
$$\int\left[U-H(q,p)\right]e^{-\beta H(q,p)}d\omega=0$$
I obtain
$$\frac{\partial^{2}U}{\partial\beta^{2}}=\left\langle \left(\Delta E\right)^{3}\right\rangle $$
But, now I'm stuck. How can I link that who results to show the first statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, using the partition function $Z=\sum_n e^{-\beta E_n}$, you have
$$
\langle E\rangle=\frac{1}{Z}\partial_{-\beta}Z,
$$$$
\langle E^2\rangle=\frac{1}{Z}\partial_{-\beta}^2Z,
$$$$
\langle E^3\rangle=\frac{1}{Z}\partial_{-\beta}^3Z.
$$
Second, you can show
$$
\langle E\rangle=\partial_{-\beta} \ln Z,
$$$$
\langle (\Delta E)^2\rangle=\langle (E-\langle E\rangle)^2\rangle=\partial_{-\beta}^2 \ln Z,
$$$$
\langle (\Delta E)^3\rangle=\langle (E-\langle E\rangle)^3\rangle=\partial_{-\beta}^3 \ln Z.
$$
Well, it just indicates that $\langle E^n\rangle$'s are disconnected correlation functions, while $\langle (\Delta E)^n\rangle$'s connected. And at last:
$$
\langle (\Delta E)^3\rangle=\partial_{-\beta}^2 U=(k_B T^2\partial_T)^2 E=k_B^2 T^2\partial_T(T^2 C_V)=k_B^2(T^4\partial_T C_V+2T^3C_V).
$$
Aha, trumpets!